# Sharepoint desinger 2007 with sharepoint 2007 serverssss

Tags: sharepoint

i download sharepoint 2007 designer to my local machine, i want this to connect with sharepoint 2007 server which is on other machine. IS any one can help me how to start with it, i am new to share point.

Y i need this?

some in past build share point site using 2007. i am taking over this project, but i have no idea where to start.

help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

1.
Open SharePoint Designer. Click Windows `Start -> Programs -> Microsoft Office -> Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer`.

2.
Click `File` in the menu near the top of the SharePoint Designer screen and select `Open Site`.

3.
Enter the URL of your SharePoint site in the `Site name` field near the bottom of the `Open Site` dialog box. Click the `Open` button.

4.
Choose your editing option. Depending on the configuration of your SharePoint site, you can choose to edit the live site, or edit a local copy and publish that copy to the server at a later time. Click the button next to your desired option and select `OK`.

5.
Enter your username and password if prompted and click `OK`.
**SharePoint Designer is now connected with your SharePoint Server site**.

Comment: what url should i use when i select open site? i have a local copay of the site at my C drive.    Error : Server error: there is no web named "c:\mysite"

Comment: The URL is SharePoint site URL and it is exactly as you see the URL in browser address bar when you open the SharePoint site in browser. Please clarify the situatuion by answering these questions: 1. The local copy that you have, is it a SharePoint site and can you browse it in browser. 2. Do you have SharePoint Server installed on your local machine?

Comment: or can you let me know . how to open a webcite from server. i have two folder given.

Comment: i got two folders. But i have no idea what is in these folders. i try to open the site and give my c:\folder name.  This site build in sharepoint, i sure about it. Sharepoint is remote. answer to queistion two is i jsut have two folders.

Comment: two folders are , wwwsroot and wwwroot

Comment: Well the sites in your local folder are not SharePoint sites. SharePoint sites are on the SharePoint Server, which is on remote machine. So don't look into your C: drive. Now if you want to open a SharePoint site in Designer, then follow what the steps in my post above.

Comment: Now you can also open any local folder in Designer by following the same steps. But if you don't know about their contents, then what will you do by opening them in designer? This however has got nothing to do with SharePoint.

Comment: i need to modify site , which is build in sharepoint. how should i start. i will really appreciate  your help

Comment: i followed your steps. when i come to open site dailog box it ask me site name. ( i opened designer from local machine , then give the path of server on top bar and in bottom bar it asking me site name). on server i have two folder related to this site.